# Efficient way to compare a datetime to midnight in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select from a SQL Server table where a datetime field is > than midnight of the current date.

I'm using the following but would like to ask if there is a more efficient way to do it?

```
 WHERE start_time > (Select DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())))
```

Comment: At least easier to read: `WHERE start_time > DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()))`

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Lots of ways of doing this. Perhaps:
`WHERE start_time > cast(getdate() as date)`

Answer (score 5):

If you convert or cast the current date to a date instead of datetime, I believe you can use that in your WHERE because the date data type is set to midnight:

```
WHERE start_time > CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
```

OR

```
WHERE start_time > CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
```

Comment: As long as you're running SQL Server 2008 or later. SQL Server 2005 doesn't have the __date__ data type.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I need to keep as datetime as I have to compare exact start times at point in the application.  Simply changing to DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())) has knocked a couple of seconds off - it was a large unioned query

Comment: You are keeping the field as a datetime, you are only converting getdate() in that one instance to a date. You should not have downstream issues using the fields as datetime if you use this method

Answer (score 0):

Here are some approaches. SQL Server 2012 added some functions to compose dates from parts, but it can be accomplished in earlier versions also.

```
DECLARE
@dt_now date = GETDATE();

-- requires SQL Server 2012 or later
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@dt_now), MONTH(@dt_now), DAY(@dt_now), 0, 0, 0, 0);

-- available for SQL Server 2005 or later
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CAST(MONTH(@dt_now) AS varchar) + '/'
                    + CAST(DAY(@dt_now) AS varchar) + '/'
                    + CAST(YEAR(@dt_now) AS varchar), 101);
```